# How to configure STM32 timer to trigger interrupt on every increment/decrement?

Tags: stm32, stm32f7

I try to interface a rotary encoder with STM32F7. A timer (TIM1) should count a value between 0-100 and trigger an interrupt every time the value is incremented or decremented.

The counting works but I only can configure an interrupt on every update event. (if counter overflows/underflows)

How can I configure such a timer?

[image]

```
static void MX_TIM1_Init(void)
{

  TIM_Encoder_InitTypeDef sConfig;
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig;

  htim1.Instance = TIM1;
  htim1.Init.Prescaler = 0;
  htim1.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim1.Init.Period = 99;
  htim1.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim1.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
  htim1.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  sConfig.EncoderMode = TIM_ENCODERMODE_TI1;
  sConfig.IC1Polarity = TIM_ICPOLARITY_RISING;
  sConfig.IC1Selection = TIM_ICSELECTION_DIRECTTI;
  sConfig.IC1Prescaler = TIM_ICPSC_DIV1;
  sConfig.IC1Filter = 0;
  sConfig.IC2Polarity = TIM_ICPOLARITY_RISING;
  sConfig.IC2Selection = TIM_ICSELECTION_DIRECTTI;
  sConfig.IC2Prescaler = TIM_ICPSC_DIV1;
  sConfig.IC2Filter = 0;
  if (HAL_TIM_Encoder_Init(&htim1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger2 = TIM_TRGO2_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim1, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Edge Detector Trigger**
[TI1F_ED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EN06U.png)
Example for STM32F030F4P6:

```html
/* Trigger Edge Detector */
/* 100: TI1 Edge Detector (TI1F_ED) */
TIM3->SMCR &= ~(TIM_SMCR_TS_0 | TIM_SMCR_TS_1);
TIM3->SMCR |= TIM_SMCR_TS_2;
/* 1: Trigger interrupt enabled. */
TIM3->DIER |= TIM_DIER_TIE;
NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM3_IRQn);
```

```html
void TIM3_IRQHandler(void){
    if(TIM3->SR & TIM_SR_TIF){
        
    /* Here code */
    
        /* Interrupt enabled */
        TIM3->SR &= ~TIM_SR_TIF;
    }
}
```

More infromation:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1CPk9UD4440
https://cxemka.com/71-podklyuchenie-enkodera-dupa-k-stm32-cmsis-i-hal.html

Answer (score -1):

I believe that the capture interrupt mechanism would work in encoder mode, so setting `TIM1->DIER |= TIM_DIER_CC1IE` should generate an interrupt every time the counter is changing.

If the above doesn't work, then set up an EXTI interrupt on the *other input pin*, i.e. the one mapped to channel 2, which is not changing the counter directly. This way you would get a stable reading of the counter value.

Answer (score -2):

It is not possible directly - but you can set the PWM with and then set the EXTI interrupt on the that line.

Comment: It is possible that the interrupt is faster than the encoder counter thus if you get an EXTI interrupt, the counter value isn't updated yet. This is a bad idea.

Comment: exti from pwm generated by the timer. So how to hell the counter could not be updated

Comment: btwq http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/54/0f/67/eb/47/34/45/40/DM00042534.pdf/files/DM00042534.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00042534.pdf encoder mode

Comment: I read this document. My understanding is that the interrupt is not generated by the timer but a external line rising/falling edge. In this case, the counter can be updated later then the line. I know somebody that got exactly this issue. But if you really know an interrupt which is generated by the timer and NOT by the pin edges, then please explain it to me. That was exactly my question.

Comment: @Caniko it is simple - your timer which counts generates the PWM on the **internal  pin**. You set the |EXTI on this pin (line). The edges are generated by the timer and the pin with exit has no connection (electrical) with the encoder pins.

Comment: @Caniko The interrupt won't be faster than the counter when you're not using the input filter.